# "trivial" exact sequence

Tags: exact-sequence

Let $A=B=C=\{0\}$.

Is $A\stackrel{f}\to B\stackrel{g}\to  C$ a splitting exact sequence?

We have $Im(f)=ker(g)$ and there is an $h:C\to B$ such that $g\circ h=id_C$ so it should yield a splitting exact sequence but it's so trivial I don't know whether this is true.

Comment: "it's so trivial I don't know whether this is true" Generally, the solution to this is to read the relevant definition carefully word-for-word, because (usually) it either explicitly excludes your trivial example, or it doesn't, in which case your example is allowed.

Comment: That's why I'm here. In the definition I was given it wasn't excluded.

Comment: Don't you trust $\{0\}=\{0\}\oplus\{0\}$?

Comment: In that case, it is allowed. Usually, when trivial cases are excluded, it is because it leads to cumbersome phrasing down the line ($1$ isn't a prime, because if $1$ were a prime, then almost every single theorem relevant to prime numbers would say "prime other than $1$" all the time). I see no immediate problem with allowing $0\to 0\to 0$ to be called a split sequence.

Comment: @Arthur Yes, that is exactly my reason for this question. I remembered that fields are required (for some mysterious reason) to be non-trivial.

Comment: @Buh Yes, fields are usually required to be non-trivial because the [field with one element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_with_one_element) is a very strange creature. So every result would have "a field with at least $2$ elements" or "a field with $1\neq 0$" to avoid that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any *short* exact sequence $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$ is split whenever $A=\{0\}$ or $C=\{0\}$. The reason is that the definition applies.